# When does Raven's Choice occur in relation to the main game?

Tags: gravity-rush-2

I have the *Raven's Choice* DLC which I got before ever starting the game. Obviously, starting the game for the first time, I was thrown into the main game (just like in the previous game) and after the intro sequence, I received an announcement saying that the DLC was available from the title screen. After quitting the game, I saw an option on the title screen separating the main game from the DLC.

I know that at the start of the game, Kat and Raven have been separated because of some events and the cover for the game talks about being able to use Combination Attacks with Raven so I know this means I’ll be reunited with her again

> and also I saw a cutscene "comic" image of Kat and Raven back in Kat's pipe in Hekseville in the same bed.

Thus, I am wondering, when does the DLC occur in regards to the main game and more importantly would I get any spoilers plot-wise if I played it at that point? I’m looking for a yes or no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raven's Choice takes place between GR and GR2.

I would advise playing it after the main game, I haven't finished the DLC myself but reading the plot shows it does touch on some minor plot points from the main game, while not necessarily spoiling them.